# Argument of type { someParam: boolean } is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<string | boolean>'

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I m gotting the error mentioned on the title while I m trying to add some params to the navigator screen using the current generated type
note that it's working on other screens and also on this I can access to it when typing `route.params`

```
// Screen is an object of screens name
type RouteType<T extends Object, S extends Screen> = RouteProp<
  {
    [key in S]: T;
  },
  S
>;

export type NavigationInjectedProps<T extends Object, S extends Screen> = {
  navigation: NavigationProp<T>;
  route: RouteType<T, S>;
};
```

the props added to my component

```
type Props = NavigationInjectedProps<
   params,
  'ExampleComp'
>;
```

params

```
interface params {
  someParam: boolean;
  someOtherParam: string;
}
```

method to set the param where the error is shown

```
export default ExampleComp ({navigation}:Props) {

useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({ someParam : false }); // got error here
  }, [navigation]);

}

...
```

thanks.

Comment: `Partial<string | boolean>` is already a big red flag!

Comment: Missing definition for `NavigationProp` which is likely the cause of the problem above.

Comment: `NavigationInjectedProps` contains the definition

Comment: That's where you use it, not where you define it.